# alt tab stopped working properly suddenly in Ubuntu 12:04 Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity

I have been working on my laptop since morning and suddenly before some time my <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> functionalist stopped working properly.

Some times it switches between the windows some times not, even if it switches, it only switches to the next window and does not show the preview of all windows.

Suddenly, once in a while it shows previews of all windows but then too it switches only to the next window and goes away.

I logged out and logged and even restarted the machine but that did not help

I don't know that the hell happened to Ubuntu to stop it working suddenly.

I am so fed up to go to the touchpad now and then to switch windows :(

> I have Chrome, Sublime Text, Pidgin and Terminal windows open.

If I am on Chrome it switches to Pidgin's conversation window after few <kbd>alt-tab</kbd>.

but then again only after few tries it switches back to Chrome.

In between one in a while the switcher preview is displayed for few seconds and disappears.

This same happens when I am switching between Sublime and Terminal.

In all its happening for all windows that are open.

I think I noticed when I do <kbd>alt + tab</kbd> it mostly detects it only as <kbd>tab</kbd>

Any solutions?

Comment: What would really help here is an example of the problem, something like: "I have the following windows open: X, Y, and Z.  When I press Alt-Tab, I expect it to .... .  Instead what happens is ... ."  Otherwise, it's a bit too vague to know what exactly your problem is.

Comment: This sounds much like a bug report and if so would be off-topic here. Any chance you installed `CCSM` or made a lot of customisations to your desktop?

Comment: @TomBrossman I have installed ccsm long ago and have not done any heavy customizations, and it was working of lately  untill recently it started happening suddenly. I am just clean bowled

Comment: @TomBrossman, I removed `CCSM` but still no luck :(

Comment: I asked about CCSM as it can customise Alt + Tab behaviour, try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/17610/12864) for how to reset Unity in case this is the root cause.

Comment: @SteveKroon , I thing when I do <kbd>alt + tab</kbd> it mostly detects it only as <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: Does your "Alt" key work for other purposes (e.g. launching the HUD)?

Comment: @SteveKroon, yes it works

Comment: Same problem.  I think it's chrome?